# Переадресация доменов

Tags: dns

Добрый вечер, такая ситуация:
На одном днс прописано 10+ доменов
Как сделать переадресацию на определенную страницу основного домена?

Comment: Переадресацию кого? Вы же понимаете, что единственное, чем заведует DNS - это преобразование доменов в IP, и понятия "страница" там не существует?

Comment: @Etki CNAME запись не поможет в этом случае?

Comment: @GrayHoax каким образом CNAME обеспечит редирект на конкретную страницу?

Comment: Да, вы правы, это здесь не поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS сам по себе не позволяет переадресовывать на отдельные страницы Web-серверов (я так понимаю, здесь речь идёт о Web).
Дело в том, что хотя DNS и используется для преобразования адресов в том числе HTTP-серверов, о HTTP он ничего не знает. А понятне *страницы* это понятие Web-сервера.

Что вы можете сделать чтобы решить вашу задачу?

Вы можете создать HTTP-сервер, на который указать все ваши адреса. Его настроить так, что все эти DNS-имена будут вести на определённую страницу искомого сервера: редиректить на неё или просто работать в прокси-режиме.

Решить эту задачу может nginx, apache или другой универсальный web-сервер.

Вот пример настройки nginx, работающего в proxy-режиме:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server1.example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://server0.example.com/pageX/;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_connect_timeout   150;
    proxy_send_timeout      100;
    proxy_read_timeout      100;
    proxy_buffers           4 32k;
    client_max_body_size    8m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

  }
}
```

В данном случае при обращении на сервер `server1.example.com` будет показываться содержимое страницы `server0.example.com/pageX/`, но обратите внимание, что тут *не будет перенаправления клиента*, сервер будет сам считывть страницу и отдавать её.

Перенаправление, конечно же, тоже можно настроить. Это тоже делается средствами web-сервера, в данном случае nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете в ввиду перенаправление на веб-страницу. И чтобы реализовать этот механизм потребуется HTTP-сервер обрабатывающий запрос HTTP-клиента и его перенаправляющий. Причем это перенаправление можно произвести используя разные техники. А средствами DNS вы можете отдать клиенту другое имя хоста или FQDN через запись CNAME, но это не веб-страница.